# How to post `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` properly?

Tags: ios, uikit, device-orientation

I'm trying to notify my `UIViewController` re-apply layout by device orientation. To do this, I'm posting `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` to default center. It worked, but without rotation animation. I think there is something I had missing. How can I post `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` properly?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];
```

instead (replace LandscapeRight as needed), as you should not be posting system notifications.

Answer (score 1):

It will post events for you:

```
- (void)updateOrientation
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
}
```

But, of course, you should be more neat and call `[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]` when you need to stop rotations, and then you call `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];` when you are ready to handle it again: it will call all necessary callbacks for your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should be anything when you try to post that. 
Instead, it is posted automatically when there is an orientation change. You should be adding a observer for hat notification if you want to use it.